# Apache Virtual host goes to Internet

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have setup a virtualhost in ubuntu 18.04:
I created cicles.almata.com in sites avalaible and ln in sites-enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName cicles.almata.com
    ServerAlias www.cicles.almata.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cicles
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorcicles.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accesscicles.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also setup /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 cicles.almata.com
```

But when i type cicles.almata.com i go to internet, it appears a Plesk webpage.

[image]

I thought it would display the content of /var/www/html/cicles/index.html....Shouldn't apache look at local virtual hosts, setup and then if nothing matches then go "outside" to internet. ???
Then if i setup a virtual host, then i must assure it doesnt exist its domain in internet ??
Is htere a way on a local machine to fix this ?

Thanks

Apache2.4, Ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 0):

I just answer here just in case someone have similar problem. The problem were with the proxy. Dont know why exactly, if you put cicles.almata.com in the browser, it goes to internet... but another webs like example.com didnt.
So to avoid this in the browser settings i put

[image]

This is in Network preferences in Firefox Options/Preferences.